# Can't install latest supertuxkart version on 18.04

Tags: 18.04, dependencies, games

The supertuxkart dev ppa recently got an update. When I try to upgrade the app, I get a dependency error.

```
 supertuxkart : Depends: supertuxkart-data (= 1.2~rc1+build4~ubuntu18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
```

Versions are as follows:

```
Where                          supertuxkart                  supertuxkart-data   
18.04 repos                    0.9.3-1                       0.9.3-1
Previous dev ppa version       1.1+build4~ubuntu18.04.1      1.1+build4~ubuntu18.04.1
Current dev ppa version        1.2~rc1+build4~ubuntu18.04.1  1.2~rc1+build4~ubuntu18.04.1
```

The error message seems to be asking for the version of `supertuxkart-data` that is in fact available, so I'm confused.

A new install on a different system results in the same error.

How can I obtain the latest supertuxkart awesomeness?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whoops, that's my fault.  I'm pushing a new build to the PPA right now with the bad dependency removed.  Sorry about that! ;)

EDIT: Builds are pushed.  Let me know if you have any more issues! :)

Comment: Fixed by new build. Was able to uninstall the font packages. Thanks for the awesome game and the responsiveness.

Answer (score 2):

There are two font packages required which do not exist in the 18.04 repos.

Namely, [fonts-noto-ui-core](https://packages.ubuntu.com/eoan/fonts-noto-ui-core) and [fonts-noto-core](https://packages.ubuntu.com/eoan/fonts-noto-core).

Fortunately, the `eoan` versions of the packages are installable on 18.04

Download them from the links above, install them with `gdebi`, then `supertuxkart` installs.

Happy karting!

Comment: I would recommend you to contact PPA owners about missed font packages. They can package them for 18.04 I hope.

Comment: @N0rbert Agreed. I sent them a message.

Comment: Great! Have a nice gameplay :)

Answer (score 1):

The version from the Snap Store works for me. Open Ubuntu Software, search for SuperTuxKart, then install the one where the source is "Snap Store" or "snapcraft.io". Snaps like this one update every week. The nice thing about snaps is that all the dependencies are bundled into one thing (you don't have to install anything extra). The app icon and ratings look like this: [App icon with the words "SuperTuxKart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/piZmo.png) [Top of app details page (notice the "Permissions" button will appear when you install it)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPvyR.png)

Comment: I don't do snaps.

Comment: (Also, the snap is still at version 1.1 AFAIK)